# Converting an image to black and white ( not gray scal)

Tags: java, image-processing

hello I am converting an image from color to pure black and white the result is a dark image. I am not getting the reason. Following is my code its been inspired by other codes on SO.
Any guidance would be helpfull.

```
BufferedImage coloredImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/discusit/ninja.png"));
BufferedImage blackNWhite = new BufferedImage(coloredImage.getWidth(),coloredImage.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
Graphics2D graphics = blackNWhite.createGraphics();
graphics.drawImage(blackNWhite, 0, 0, null);
```

I am not getting what I am doing wrong. Any more ideas using any other open source library would be fine.

WORKING :::::

```
BufferedImage coloredImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/abc/ninja.png"));
BufferedImage blackNWhite = new BufferedImage(coloredImage.getWidth(),coloredImage.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
Graphics2D graphics = blackNWhite.createGraphics();
graphics.drawImage(coloredImage, 0, 0, null);

ImageIO.write(blackNWhite, "png", new File("/home/abc/newBlackNWhite.png"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually convert the colored image to black and white; you're creating a new, blank image the same size as the old one. You need to actually do something to process the old image.

Comment: @johnchen902: No, wait! I misunderstood `createGraphics`; your answer was better!

Comment: Mine mentioned nothing about `createGraphics`, either.

Comment: @user2357112 my fault I placed the wrong code, I am editing an placing the right code right now... sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Done ... :) :) :) while writing back the image I have to use the old one(coloredImage) ... :) :)

Comment: @user2357112 I am adding the code to my question thank you for your tips ... :) :)

Comment: @gpasch: I dunno; you'd have to ask the questioner. Personally, I would have accepted johnchen902's answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you want control over the so-called thresholding process, here a ready-to-use snippet. Start with 128 as a threshold, then you get what the other methods do.

```java
/**
 * Converts an image to a binary one based on given threshold
 * @param image the image to convert. Remains untouched.
 * @param threshold the threshold in [0,255]
 * @return a new BufferedImage instance of TYPE_BYTE_GRAY with only 0'S and 255's
 */
public static BufferedImage thresholdImage(BufferedImage image, int threshold) {
    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    result.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    WritableRaster raster = result.getRaster();
    int[] pixels = new int[image.getWidth()];
    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        raster.getPixels(0, y, image.getWidth(), 1, pixels);
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            if (pixels[i] < threshold) pixels[i] = 0;
            else pixels[i] = 255;
        }
        raster.setPixels(0, y, image.getWidth(), 1, pixels);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To actually convert the image to black and white, you could iterate over each pixel and average the colors at that location.  For example

```
for(int x=0;x<width;x++){
    for(int y=0;y<height;y++){
        Color color = getPixelAt(x,y);
        int newColor = (color.getRed()+color.getGreen()+color.getBlue())/3;
        Color newPixelColor = new Color(newColor,newColor,newColor);
        //set new pixel
    }
}
```

There are more accurate ways to convert color to black and white though.  Our eyes actually perceive more green than red, and more red than blue.  Because of this, a more true conversion would weight each of the color componets appropriately to produce a better perceived average.

Weighting I've used that produces good results is as follows:

```
int newColor = (int)(color.getGreen()*.7+color.getRed()*.2+color.getBlue()*.1);
```

Edit:

If by black and white you mean an image with only black pixels and white pixels, you could do this by assigning all pixels with an average less than a threshold value to black, and all pixels with an average greater to white.  Like so:

```
static final int BLACK = 0;
static final int WHITE = 255;
int threshold = 127;
if(newColor < threshold)
    newColor = BLACK;
else
    newColor = WHITE;
```

Comment: That's actually converting it to gray values, not black and white. For the latter you need to threshold the image.

Comment: @Mathias thanks, don't know how I made that mistake given its in the title! I've corrected my answer.

Comment: I find the weighing of color components interesting.

Answer (score 2):

View a model

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ImageTool {
    public static void toBlackAndWhite(BufferedImage img) {
        toBlackAndWhite(img, 50);
    }
    public static void toBlackAndWhite(BufferedImage img, int precision) {
        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();

        precision = (0 <= precision && precision <= 100) ? precision : 50;

        int limit = 255 * precision / 100;

        for(int i = 0, j; i < w; ++i) {
            for(j = 0; j < h; ++j) {
                Color color = new Color(img.getRGB(i, j));
                if(limit <= color.getRed() || limit <= color.getGreen() || limit <= color.getBlue()) {
                    img.setRGB(i, j, Color.WHITE.getRGB());
                } else {
                    img.setRGB(i, j, Color.BLACK.getRGB());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try with main code

```
for(Integer i : new Integer[] {0, 30, 70, 100}) {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("in.png"));
    ImageTool.toBlackAndWhite(img, i);
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("out_" + i + ".png"));
}
```

and you will see the result.

Answer (score 2):

There are many approaches to represent images using just black and white pixels and for different kind of applications such as compression, impression, arts and analysis.

The example below uses [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net) and shows three different ways to represent images in black and white. In the case of halftone technique, an illusion of shades of gray is created, but if zoom in you'll see just white and black pixels.

**input:**

[image]

**thresholding:**

[image]

**halftone:**

[image]

**halftone zoom:**

[image]

**circles:**

[image]

```
import static marvin.MarvinPluginCollection.*;

public class BlackAndWhiteExamples {

    public BlackAndWhiteExamples(){
        MarvinImage original = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/lena3.jpg");
        MarvinImage output = original.clone();
        thresholding(original, output, 190);
        // 1. Thresholding
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(output, "./res/lena3_thresholding.png");
        halftoneErrorDiffusion(original, output);
        // 2. Halftoning
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(output, "./res/lena3_error_diffusion.png");
        // 3. Circles
        halftoneCircles(original, output, 15, 0, 0);
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(output, "./res/lena3_circles.png");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    new BlackAndWhiteExamples();    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a typo:

```
graphics.drawImage(blackNWhite, 0, 0, null);
```

Replace `blackNWhite` with the image you want to process with

```
graphics.drawImage(coloredImage, 0, 0, null);
```

And now `blackNWhite` contains the black-and-white version of `coloredImage`. Maybe you will want another assignment:

```
coloredImage = blackNWhite;
```